# Wiremock not returning saved responses

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a wiremock standalone server, which is proxying all requests even if a response is already saved on root dir.

Here is my configuration:

```
        WireMockConfiguration wireMockConfiguration = new WireMockConfiguration()
            .port(server.getPort())
            .withRootDirectory("./mocks/" + server.getRootDir())
            .notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true));

        mockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfiguration);
```

Here is my config for stub mapping, this code runs only if "proxy-mode" property on application.properties is true. My Stub mapping:

```
    mockServer.loadMappingsUsing(stubMappings -> {
        RequestPattern requestPattern = RequestPatternBuilder
                .newRequestPattern(RequestMethod.ANY, WireMock.anyUrl())
                .build();

        ResponseDefinition responseDef = ResponseDefinitionBuilder
                .responseDefinition()
                .proxiedFrom("https://myProxyUrl.com")
                .build();
        StubMapping proxyBasedMapping = new StubMapping(requestPattern, responseDef);
        proxyBasedMapping.setPriority(10);

        stubMappings.addMapping(proxyBasedMapping);
    });
```

If I set "proxy-mode" to false, it returns saved responses.

What I want is to proxy requests that are not saved and to return saved responses.

What am I missing?

[UPDATE]

Saved responses are returned after server is restarted.
It's possible to save and return saved response at runtime?